# Dancer2 - Cannot deploy with Apache2 using Plack

Tags: apache2, dancer, plack

I am trying to deploy Dancer2 app using Plack on Apache2. But after changing all the configurations on port 80 - it shows me directory listing instead of the application itself

Here is my running application on local:

> root@dancer-cmuscheduler:/home/ADI/dancer_scheduler# plackup
>   bin/app.psgi  HTTP::Server::PSGI: Accepting connections at
>   http://0:5000/

This runs just fine on port 5000.

However, I would like to deploy on apache2.  Here is my configruations:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /data

        SetEnv DANCER_ENVIRONMENT "production"

        <Directory /var/www/cmuscheduler>
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>

        <Location />
            SetHandler perl-script
            PerlResponseHandler Plack::Handler::Apache2
            PerlSetVar psgi_app /var/www/cmuscheduler/bin/app.psgi
        </Location>

        ErrorLog  ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

I have been trying to debug for 4 hours now.  The funny thing is there is no helpful logs in the log file associated that would nudge me in the right direction

> [Thu Jul 14 02:23:14.424149 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 7468:tid
>   140401436669824] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming
>   normal operations [Thu Jul 14 02:23:14.424306 2016] [core:notice] [pid
>   7468:tid 140401436669824] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

Please advice

Comment: Dumb question, but just to make sure...did you reload the Apache config after making your changes?

Comment: Also, your user prompt shows that your app is in /home/ADI/dancer_scheduler, but your Apache config has /var/www/cmuscheduler. Is one of those a symlink?

Comment: Have you checked that your vhost configuration is actually being picked up? `apachectl -S`

Comment: Oops turns out sites-available was not included part of apache2.conf

Comment: Does that mean you were able to get this working? If so, please write an answer showing what you did to fix it so future visitors with the same issue can see.